# How to select second row from bottom with :nth-last-child?

Tags: html, css

I have 6 rows and I need to select 2 rows from bottom like this

```
<div>row1 - not selected</div>
<div>row2 - not selected</div>
<div>row3 - not selected</div>
<div>row4 - selected</div>
<div>row5 - selected</div>
<div>row6 - not selected</div>
```

Comment: nth-child(4) and nth-child(5)

Comment: @AHaworth But how can I do it dynamic ?

Comment: define *dynamic*

Comment: I have this list and below I have button ( Load More ) on click I load 6 more elements

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood, I thought you had 6 elements and wanted the 4th and 5th. Could you explain a bit more what you want?

Comment: As  you are adding 6 items at a time, are you wanting to select the 4th and 5th elements plus the 10th and 11th elements and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Nth-last-child needs a parent to work properly. It selects its child's position. If you have a list of divs (like in your example) and after that something else it won't work.

```
// HTML
<div class="a">
  <div>row1 - not selected</div>
  <div>row2 - not selected</div>
  <div>row3 - not selected</div>
  <div>row4 - selected</div>
  <div>row5 - selected</div>
  <div>row6 - not selected</div>
</div>
```

```
// CSS
.a div:nth-last-child(2), .a div:nth-last-child(3){
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: But how can I do it dynamic ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by dynamic? Could you explain and provide more code (js)?

Answer (score 0):

The `:nth-child()` or `:nth-last-child()` CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position among a group of siblings. And `:nth-last-child()`  counting from the end. So, dynamic code:

```css
.parent div:nth-last-child(2),
.parent div:nth-last-child(3) {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>row1 - not selected</div>
  <div>row2 - not selected</div>
  <div>row3 - not selected</div>
  <div>row4 - selected</div>
  <div>row5 - selected</div>
  <div>row6 - not selected</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `:nth-last-child(2n+0)`. This will select the last child from the bottom. Hope this helps.

For more information on `:nth-last-child()` see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child